# Google's OpenID identifier is different depending on the "consumer" domain name. How to avoid problems if domain name needs to change?

Tags: openid, identity, dotnetopenauth

I'm currently testing an OpenID implementation, and I'm noticing that Google sends a different identifier for different consuming host name / domain name, even for the same user.  For example, Google sends a different identifier when the requesting site is `localhost`, compared to the identifier they send when the requesting site is `127.0.0.1` for the same user.

Note: I haven't actually tested this using public domain names, but I can't see why the behavior would be any different.

My concern with Google's behavior is that if we ever choose to change our website domain name in the future, then users will no longer be able to log in to the website using Google's OpenId as the identity provider.  This seems to be a big problem.  Am I missing something, or are all OpenID consuming sites faced with this potential problem?

I've also tested this with MyOpenId, but the identifier that MyOpenId creates is fixed, so this wouldn't be a problem with them.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/googles-openids-are-unique-per-domain/

Comment: has this problem been sorted out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Google OpenID most important technical issue](http://groups.google.com/group/google-federated-login-api/web/the-most-important-technical-issue-in-using-the-google-accounts-api?pli=1). Some infos there. Basically a link taken from the accounts section of stackoverflow.com ;)

-sa

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the OpenID URLs returned by Google depend on the `openid.realm` value that is used. Also, I just tried the OpenID process with a realm set to `http://MYREALM` and `openid.return_to` set to `http://localhost/openid.php`, but received an HTTP 400 Bad Request. Apparently, Google checks that the realm has the same domain (and probably port) as the "return to" URL.

One idea for a work-around is to store the Gmail address associated with the OpenID. Whenever you request a Google OpenID, always request the user's email address via Attribute Exchange's `http://axschema.org/contact/email` type. If you ever change domains, you can associate the new OpenID URL with their account based on the email address.

Note: It is **imperative** that you verify the HMAC-SHA1 signature. Otherwise, anyone would be able to "return to" your web application's OpenID checkauth action with a constructed email address, allowing them to take over someone's account if they know the target's Gmail address.

When a user is logging in with their Google Account for the first time after the switch, the migration procedure is:

1. Send a POST request to `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud` with the following parameters:

   ```
    +---------------------+----------------------------------+
    | openid.ns           | http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0 |
    | openid.mode         | associate                        |
    | openid.assoc_type   | HMAC-SHA1                        |
    | openid.session_type | no-encryption                    |
    +---------------------+----------------------------------+
   ```

   (replace `openid.realm=http://NEWREALM` as appropriate)

   The response will be something like:

   ```
    ns:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
    session_type:no-encryption
    assoc_type:HMAC-SHA1
    assoc_handle:B5hJNa39Cl39BXSOKMqkPpk03rJmE0GI6EhHBkvfLOBFAMMQX67HjuFq
    expires_in:46800
    mac_key:F5XUXvoYutLvFv4IzJS0diytLmbe
   ```
2. With the redirect to the Service URI, `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud`, mode 'checkid_setup', make sure to send the assoc_handle that was previously obtained as well as require the user's email address via Attribute Exchange. In other words, be sure to send the following, additional parameters:

   ```
    +----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
    | openid.assoc_handle  | B5hJNa39Cl39BXSOKMqkPpk03rJmE0GI6EhHBkvfLOBFAMMQX67HjuFq |
    | openid.ns.ax         | http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0                             |
    | openid.ax.mode       | fetch_request                                            |
    | openid.ax.type.email | http://axschema.org/contact/email                        |
    | openid.ax.required   | email                                                    |
    +----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
   ```

   The "return to" request will include the important parameters `openid_signed`, `openid_sig`, and `openid_ext1_value_email`.
3. Follow [the OpenID Authentication 2.0 Specification's procedure for generating the signature](https://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#generating_signatures). If the base64-encoding of the HMAC-SHA1 signature is not the same as the `openid_sig` value, then the signature is invalid. Note that the MAC key in this example is `F5XUXvoYutLvFv4IzJS0diytLmbe`. Use whatever Google's server sent back with the association request.

[Google's Federated Login documentation page states](https://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) that `http://axschema.org/contact/email` "[r]equests the user's gmail address". Presumably, once a Google Account is created then the "Gmail" email address is fixed. But, if this assumption is not valid, then it is not safe to use this procedure because a malicious user could change their email address as returned by the Federated Login Service to whatever the email address is of the account that they wish to steal.

Just to be on the safe side, before activating the new OpenID, send an email verification request to the email address. The verification link would contain a nonce associated with the new OpenID. Once the link is clicked, the new OpenID would be fully associated with the user's account as receipt of the nonce would verify the association between email address and new OpenID URL.

See also: [openid.sig -- How is it generated?](https://groups.google.com/group/google-federated-login-api/browse_thread/thread/c286f5844a964ad7/b0eb382ca70e16e2)

Comment: about storing emails ( I do this), but with checking the HMAC-SHA1 not sure, because I'm using the the DonNetOpen Auth lib for openid so probably the lib does that

Comment: @ChuckNorris: It looks like there are classes in the `DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId` namespace to handle associations, but I am not sure at what stage in the OpenID authentication process they are used. OpenID 2.0 "return to" requests contain an assoc_handle that can be used by the web app to verify that the information came from the Service. The web app just makes a POST request to the Service URI with mode 'check_authentication' and all of the parameters referenced in the `openid.signed` parameter value. See [11.4.2. Verifying Directly with the OpenID Provider](http://tinyurl.com/3ffesj9).

Comment: @ChuckNorris: I guess just make sure that the Service URI is `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud` if the returned identity begins with `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/`. In other words, don't allow just any OpenID Provider to send back a Google OpenID. Make sure that it is Google's.

Comment: @ChuckNorris: To clarify what I mean by "at what stage", there are two ways to verify signatures (see [11.4. Verifying Signatures](https://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#verifying_signatures)). Your web app can verify the signature itself if an association was previously made (the method that my answer uses). Otherwise, it verifies the signature directly with the OpenID Provider (section 11.4.2) after the "return to" request.

Answer (score 1):

There is another possible work-around. When making the indirect authentication request (redirecting to the Service URI), send the **old** OpenID URL as the values of the `openid.claimed_id` and `openid.identity` parameters even though realm is set to the new realm.

On my developer machine, I have the domain 'thiscomputer' aliased to 127.0.0.1. When I requested authentication from Google's OpenID Provider, realm 'http://thiscomputer' and `openid.identity` and `openid.claimed_id` both set to `http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select`, I got back something like:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=VGwSBXN7Q00X4G9CTAsLPMJ3m6JaPljpkrURAUZJ
```

I then requested authentication from the OP, realm 'http://localhost' and `openid.identity` and `openid.claimed_id` both set to `http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select`. I got back something like:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=VGwSBXNwzPQk-puNdfZl4tP-s7JNHPA3WmMHozHJ
```

I then requested authentication from the OP, realm 'http://localhost' and `openid.identity` and `openid.claimed_id` both set to `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=VGwSBXN7Q00X4G9CTAsLPMJ3m6JaPljpkrURAUZJ` (the OpenID identity for my Google Account when realm is 'http://thiscomputer'). I got back:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=VGwSBXN7Q00X4G9CTAsLPMJ3m6JaPljpkrURAUZJ
```

That is, I got back the same OpenID identity URL as when realm is 'http://thiscomputer'. Thus, even though I "migrated" my OpenID-relying web app from 'thiscomputer' to 'localhost', I can still use the old OpenID identity URL.

This solution works as long as you know the user's old OpenID identity URL, perhaps because it is stored in a cookie.

One note: I tried setting `openid.identity` and `openid.claimed_id` to different values (e.g. one is `http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select` while the other is `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=VGwSBXN7Q00X4G9CTAsLPMJ3m6JaPljpkrURAUZJ` or one is `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=VGwSBXN7Q00X4G9CTAsLPMJ3m6JaPljpkrURAUZJ` and the other is `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=VGwSBXNwzPQk-puNdfZl4tP-s7JNHPA3WmMHozHJ`), but Google's OP service responded with "The page you requested is invalid."