# Communicating with Google OpenID server returns a 400

Tags: java, android, authentication, openid, single-sign-on

I'm trying to implement OpenId on Android and keep getting a 400 error. I'm guessing that I'm formatting my parameters incorrectly.

I'm basing the parameters on this browser line which correctly get's me to the server:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.return_to=http://www.example.com/checkauth
&openid.realm=http://www.example.com/
&openid.assoc_handle=ABSmpf6DNMw
&openid.mode=checkid_setup
```

Here's the code

```
            try {

         HttpsURLConnection con; 

         URL url2 = new URL("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud");
         con = (HttpsURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
         con.setDoInput(true);
         con.setDoOutput(true);

         con.setRequestMethod("GET");

         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("openid.ns", "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0"));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("openid.claimed_id", "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select"));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("openid.identity", "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select"));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("openid.return_to", "http://www.example.com/checkauth"));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("openid.realm", "http://www.example.com/"));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("openid.assoc_handle", "ABSmpf6DNMw"));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("openid.mode", "checkid_setup"));

         String content = AuthUtils.getRequestParams(params);
         con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(content.getBytes("UTF-8").length);

         OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
         writer.write(content);
         writer.close();
         out.close();            

         Log.d(TAG, "response code = " + con.getResponseCode());

         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

         String input;

         while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
             System.out.println(input);
         }
         br.close();             


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
         e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From google's [documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/fedlogininterp/openiddiscovery):

*Google's endpoint will **return a 400 on endpoint (2) if the domain provided is not hosted by Google.** So one possible strategy for an RP that wants to cater to Google Apps customers could be to first try endpoint (2), and if that returns a 400, try endpoint (1), and if that doesn't yield anything, give up. Other strategies (fetching both endpoints in parallel, for example), are possible.*

[More infos here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7603887/2015318)